# typeahead.js templating only one result

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

Can Anybody tell me why only one result is shown? The database returns multiple rows. Only the first one is displayed?

JS:

```
$('#searchbox').typeahead({
    limit: 10,
    minLength: 2,
    remote: {
      url: '/typeahead?s=%QUERY',

    },
    template: function (data) {
            return '<p>'+ data.name+'</p>';
        }
});
```

PHP (Laravel):

```
$input = Input::all();
$results = array();
$getshops = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT id, shop FROM shops WHERE shop LIKE '%".$input['s']."%'");
foreach($getshops as $shop){
    $results[] = array('id' => $shop->id, 'name' => beautifyshops($shop->shop));
}

return Response::json($results);
```

Comment: no one? Is the question phrased wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filter function remote.

remote: {

```
            url: '/typeahead?s=%QUERY',
            filter: function(parsedResponse) {
                return _.map(parsedResponse, function(res){
                    return {
                        value: res,
                    }
                });
            }
   }
```

it'll return all the suggestions returned from server.